# How to move circle with mouse in delphi?

Tags: delphi, shapes

How to move circle with mouse in delphi?

```
circle:Shape;
```

Comment: How much do you have so far? Is the circle represented by a `TShape` component, or it is something that you're drawing for yourself on a larger canvas object?

Comment: It is TShape. I dont known what event choose to make circle move by mouse.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to convert the Mouse X,Y client coordinates that you get from MouseMove on your Control to the Parent's client using `ClientToScreen` and `ScreenToClient`.

The following procedure moves the center of a Control to the point (X,Y) in it's client coordinates:

```
procedure MoveControl(AControl: TControl; const X, Y: Integer);
var
  lPoint: TPoint;
begin
  lPoint := AControl.Parent.ScreenToClient(AControl.ClientToScreen(Point(X, Y)));
  AControl.Left := lPoint.X - AControl.Width div 2;
  AControl.Top := lPoint.Y - AControl.Height div 2;
end;
```

Now to move your TShape when when it is clicked, you have to provide the following MouseMove event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.ShapeToMoveMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if ssLeft in Shift then // only move it when Left-click is down
    MoveControl(Sender as TControl, X, Y);
end;
```

And to test it, drop a button in your Form with this code:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TShape.Create(nil) do
  begin
    Name := Format('ShapeToMove%d',[Self.ControlCount + 1]);
    Parent := Self; // Parent will free it
    Shape := stCircle;
    Width := 65;
    Height := 65;
    OnMouseMove := ShapeToMoveMouseMove;
  end;
end;
```

Now, that's a minimalist example, but it should get you started.
For fun, just hook  other controls with this MouseMove event handler... :-)

Comment: i thought the 'owner' freed it, the parent passes messages on, like wm_paint. I'd change the constructor to create(self)

Comment: The owner or the parent will free it, whoever shoots first. If it's purely visual, you can leave the work to the parent, it's its role.

Answer (score 5):

If you go to my webpage, you can Find some samples (all with code included) thah can help you about this question.
["Sample for visual work with figures and plans"](http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/?p=144); Use two components for manage, move, resize and save elements visually; One for selection, movement, resize,... (TSeleccOnRuntime) and other (TSaveComps) for save the state (position, size,...).
[alt text http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/images/imagen_ej_restaurante.png](http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/images/imagen_ej_restaurante.png)

[Select Shapes Visually](http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/?p=122); Sample for explain two modes for select visually shapes and images.

[Create, move and resive controls on Runtime (like IDE)](http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/?p=170); Another sample of TSeleccOnRuntime component. Simulate and IDE.

[alt text http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/images/image_ej_form_designer.png](http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/images/image_ej_form_designer.png)

And finally another sample for [Create/destroy components in runtime and move with mouse](http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/?p=121); This sample is made without components. All code at the sample.

[alt text http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/images/imagen_ej_mover_mouse.png](http://neftali-mirror.site11.com/images/imagen_ej_mover_mouse.png)

I hope that is usefull for you.
Regards

P.D: Excuse for my bad english.

Comment: You have some VERY nice components on your site. The WMI component work is excellent. Brian.

Comment: @Neftali: Would you go look at my question below please?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386169/how-to-find-available-parallel-ports-and-their-i-o-addresses-using-delphi-and-wmi

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have too much to go on, but having something move to follow the mouse generally works like this:

Have a "IsFollowingMouse" flag somewhere.  Turn it on when you should be following the mouse.
On the form's MouseMove event, do something like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FIsFollowingMouse then
  begin
    myCircle.left := x + fShapeOffsetX;
    myCircle.top := y + fShapeOffsetY;
  end;
end;
```

The offsets are variables you use that gives the difference between the location of the mouse pointer and the top-left corner of the TShape.