# How to enumerate windows LPT ports and their I/O Range?

Tags: windows, wmi, lpt

I am working on project for controlling some devices through lpt port.
I am using inpout32.dll to get raw access to ports and now trying to enumerate all available LPT ports and get their I/O Range.

I now I can check device manager, but is there any more automated way?

Now I am trying to use WMI some sample code that should work but it does not

```
Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set parallelports = wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ParallelPort")                      

For Each port In parallelports
    q = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE PNPDeviceID = '" & port.PNPDeviceID & "'"
    Set pnpentities = wmiService.ExecQuery(q)

    For Each pnpentity In pnpentities
        wscript.echo pnpentity.PNPDeviceID
    Next
Next
```

on line 'For Each pnpentity In pnpentities' I get error.
Also I am not shure if finding corresponding entity will help me.

PS.
Finally i figured out how to enumerate lpt i/o port ranges.

```
Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Set parallelports = wmiService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ParallelPort")

For Each port In parallelports
    Set port_resources = wmiService.ExecQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_ParallelPort.DeviceID='" & port.DeviceID & "'} WHERE ResultClass = Win32_PortResource")

    For Each port_resource In port_resources
        wscript.echo port_resource.Caption
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get an error because `PNPDeviceID` contains backslashes (`\`) and backslashes in WQL queries must be doubled. Just do a replace of `\` with `\\` in `port.PNPDeviceID` before inserting it into your query, and your script will work fine:

```
strPNPDeviceID = Replace(port.PNPDeviceID, "\", "\\")
Set pnpentities = wmiService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE PNPDeviceID = '" & strPNPDeviceID & "'")
```

You may also find this question useful: [How to find available parallel ports and their I/O addresses using Delphi and WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386169/113116).