# Windows Monitoring a parallel or LPT port

Tags: c#, port, parallel-port, lpt

Does anyone know a good library to allow us to programmatically monitor a parallel port (or LPT port) in windows. There are lots of good ones for Serial ports but I have had no luck yet for parallel ports. C# would be preferred but we're happy to do the Interop work if it's c / c++.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a driver that gives access to the parallel port.  The [inpout32.dll](http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/Inpout32.dll_for_Windows_98/2000/NT/XP.html) solution is nearly universally used.  It also lets you pinvoke helper routines to execute the INP and OUT cpu instructions.  Everything you'd ever want to know about parallel ports, including coding samples for inpout32 is assembled at [Jan Axelson's home page](http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm).

Comment: Thanks Hans - it looks like a good resource. I'll have look through there and see if there are any libraries to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? [How to find available parallel ports and their I/O addresses using Delphi and WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386169/how-to-find-available-parallel-ports-and-their-i-o-addresses-using-delphi-and-wmi) its in Delphi, but I think you can find WMI in C# too.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Anuraj - I'd need to read the data going to and from the port as well as simply enumerate the available ports.